# BXNUI0005E error while doing dw001 exercise 3a

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to complete the exercise 3a in the DW001 Getting Started with IBM Bluemix course. The first exercise is to create a default node.js app in blue mix and deploy.
I am tring to create an app with the name 'akarnr-dw001-ex1' but I keep getting the following error:
BXNUI0005E: The 'akarnr-dw001-ex1' application could not be added. See the Troubleshooting topics in the IBM Bluemix Documentation to check service status, review troubleshooting information, or for information about getting help.

I have tried a number of different combinations for the unique name of the app but they keep failing.

Please help.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I have doing the following steps:   1. Select the Node.js Cloudant DB Web Starter from the Boilerplates section.   2.Enter a name for the application as akarnr-dw001-ex1. As per the instructions it says "The host name information is automatically entered. The host name must be unique on Bluemix, so enter a name with your company name or initials to make the name unique.'
6. ClickCREATE.   I then get the error mentioned in the initial question.

Comment: Have you run out of space ?  You may need to delete some previous apps if you don't have enough space to create the new one.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently experiencing some issues in Cloudant service instances provisioning, as you can see on the [Bluemix Status Page](https://status.ng.bluemix.net). This is  the reason why you are currently not able to instantiate the [Node.js Cloudant DB Web Starter](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/nodejs-cloudant-db-web-starter/) boilerplate. Please refer to the status page to know when the issue is fixed.

EDIT: The issue should now be fixed and you should be able to instantiate the boilerplate.